# 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have the 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h' located within my app:

[image]

However, this error persists:

[image]

And the PodFile:

```
platform :ios, ‘9.3’
use_frameworks!
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
    pod ‘JSQSystemSoundPlayer’
end
```

Comment: What ended up working was lowering the minimum Target from 9.3 to 9.0, I believe it has to do with the library dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need to add `pod 'JSQSoundPlayer'` it is included with the `JSQMessagesViewController` pod but also you are using the wrong quotes around the JSQSoundPlayer that is why it's a different color you need the ` single quote not the tick ' . They look very similar. Sorry if that is confusing  if you can't find it just copy the previous line and change the contents. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the line

```
#import JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h
```

with

```
@import JSQSystemSoundPlayer;
```